# Different treatment of newline after full line on windows and linux

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, output

I have the following very simplistic example program (this example is C++ but the behavior is most probably the same for any programming language):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string test;
    // One console line is 80 characters long
    // Add 80 times 'a' to the string
    test.append(80, 'a');
    // Then add the newline char and the second line
    test.append("\nSecond line");
    std::cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

It generates inconsistent console output in Windows and Linux (both in 80 characters per line mode):
Output in Windows (default command line, same in powershell):

```
aaaa(...80 times a...)aaa

Second line
```

Output in Linux (gnome console) (observe that there is no newline):

```
aaaa(...80 times a...)aaa
Second line
```

The Linux version is the one I want to have.

The behavior that Windows exhibits is understandable in the sense that it prints the 80 'a' characters and then automatically prints the newline. Afterwards the '\n' in the string is encountered and another newline is printed.
Linux just doesn't insert the newline character and just wraps the line at the end if more characters are inserted. Since no more characters are inserted this is not the case. Then the '\n' comes and it jumps to the next line.

Is there a way I can get rid of the automatic newline in windows?

Comment: See documentation for [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the `ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT` option

Comment: This suggestion sounds interesting but I'm afraid it doesn't help me. As the help article states "If this mode is disabled, the last character in the row is overwritten with any subsequent characters.". This is not what I want. If I write 81 "actual" characters (as in the 81st not being newline) I want the line to wrap and the 81st character to be displayed in the next line.

Comment: As far as i know, in windows consoles cursor position must be inside the console screen buffer. And after each write, position is incremented. With wrap enabled if the last character in the line in written, cursor column is incremented and position goes out of the buffer and CR LF is emited so cursor position becomes valid again. This is avoided when wrap is dissabled keeping the cursor on the last colum until a LF is sent. You have to leave windows handle the wrap or you will need to do it yourself, and in this case, disabling `ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT` is needed.

Comment: Ok, so the cursor handling just seems to be different in Windows and in the Linux terminals that I tried...